# Do I have to manually create the sink SQL table for a copy activity?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am a newbie of ADF and start learning from the very basic copy activity between blob storage and SQL database in Azure.

My question is for a copy activity, do I have to manually create every sink SQL-tables in the SQL-database for all csv files in blob storage that may have different columns, even I can parameterize the input and sink source?

Besides, if my csv file have like 100 columns, do I also have to manually create each sink SQL tabls by:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    column1 datatype,
    column2 datatype,
    column3 datatype,
   ....
    column100 datatype,
);
```

?

Comment: Have you tried the `Auto create table` option in ADF..? See [docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/copy-activity-in-azure-data-factory-supports-creating-destination-table-automatically/), and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#auto-create-sink-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilise the `auto create sink table` feature, available in the `Copy Activity` in ADF. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#auto-create-sink-tables).

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Great, you could accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the `auto create sink table` in other words the `Auto create table` option, table name in the Sink dataset should be entered. So;

1. Click edit the sink dataset.
2. Check "Edit" button as below.
   [image]
3. Type the schema and table name to be auto created. In this step, there is no table created, only a name given.
4. Go to your Copy data activity > Sink then check `Auto create table` option.
   [image]